# Python: toggle a button (adding more buttons)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is just the initial code for what will be an array of buttons, effecting each other.  I can't seen to understand why I keep getting this definition error!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk


def changeImage(Num):
    global buttonOn
    global buttonOff
    if Num == 1:
        if button1(image) == buttonOn:
            button1.config(image=buttonOff)
        else:
            button1.config(image=buttonOn)

root = Tk()

root.geometry('155x190')
root.title("Tile Turner")

buttonOn = PhotoImage(file="buttonPic.gif")
buttonOff = PhotoImage(file="buttonPic2.gif")

button1 = Button(image=buttonOn, width=20, height=20, command=changeImage(1))
buttonQuit = Button(text="Quit", width=10, height=0, command=root.destroy)


app.grid(column=0, row=0)
button1.grid(column=2, row = 3)
buttonQuit.grid(column=3, row = 10, columnspan = 4)

root.mainloop()
```

My definition error is in button1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jimmy/Desktop/COS 2013/Game1/small", line 23, in <module>
    button1 = Button(image=buttonOn, width=20, height=20, command=changeImage(1))
  File "C:/Users/Jimmy/Desktop/COS 2013/Game1/small", line 10, in changeImage
    if button1(image) == buttonOn:
NameError: global name 'button1' is not defined
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the image, so you can toggle it in the event handler:

```
def changeImage(num):
    global buttonOn, buttonOff, button1
    if num == 1:
        newimage = buttonOff if button1.image == buttonOn else buttonOn
        button1.image = newimage
        button1.config(image=newimage)

# ...
button1 = Button(image=buttonOn, width=20, height=20, command=lambda:changeImage(1))
button1.image = buttonOn
```

Comment: That's great! But now that I have toggled the button, I would like to return the the previous state.  How would I go about achieving that?

Comment: It will change the image each time it is clicked. That's what you mean?

Comment: Yea, That's what I'd like to have happen.  After implementing your code, it only changes to the second image.

Comment: When I try it, it swaps the images without problem. Is the `newimage = ...` statement exactly the same?

Comment: I'll just quickly try it again. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Glad it helped you, if this solved your problem feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

In this line,

```
button1 = Button(image=buttonOn, width=20, height=20, command=changeImage(1))
```

You call the function `changeImage` passing in `1` as the argument.  That function then gets evaluated and the *result* (`None` in this case) gets passed to the `command=...` default argument of the `Button` constructor.  Of course, this causes you to get the `NameError` because you call `changeImage` before you actually pass it to the Button constructor -- i.e. `button1` doesn't exist yet because it is waiting for the `changeImage` function to finish before it can continue on with constructing the `Button` instance.

You want something like:

```
button1 = Button(...,command=lambda:changeImage(1))
```

This creates a new function which when called simply calls `changeImage` with the proper argument.

To elaborate a little further on lambda, the above statement is more or less shorthand for

```
def temp_function():
    return changeImage(1)

button1 = Button(...,command=temp_function)
```

Comment: Ok thank you! Now everything works, except that the button doesn't change images after clicked. Any idea what might be causing that?  (also, I fixed the app.grid issue by just cutting it out, it wasn't needed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare `button1` (and others) above your `def changeImage(Num)`. Python reads top down so even if the function hasn't been called it, you should have everything declared before getting to that point.

Comment: By declare, do you mean moving the entire button1 definition up? I'm sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: I think the issue is in the if button1(image) == buttonOn: statement, is that possible?